# Perl Net::SMTP force auth method

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I'm trying to send mail using Perl `Net::SMTP` with auth method other than default picked GSSAPI (e.g. force PLAIN).

I have tried:

```
my $smtp;
$smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new($host, Port => $port);
$smtp->auth($user, $passwd);
```

and replacing last line with:

```
$smtp->auth('PLAIN', $user, $passwd);
```

or passing `Authen::SASL` object with selected mechanism to `$smtp->auth()`. None of the above work - debug (and mail server logs) says it still tries `AUTH GSSAPI`.

Does anyone know how to correctly force auth method in `Net::SMTP`?

My Perl version is 5.20.2-3+deb8u8 from Debian 8, packages version:

- Net::SMTP - 2.33
- Net::SMTP::SSL - 1.01
- Authen::SASL - 2.16

Comment: *I'm trying to send mail using Perl `Net::SMTP`* In 2017, that really doesn't sound like a good idea. These days we have tools like [`Email::Sender`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender).

Comment: Are you ready for ugly hacks?  Net::SMTP before 3.0 "overwrites" mechanisms configured in Authen::SASL constructor with AUTH mechanisms advertised by server in `EHLO` reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Net::SMTP version below 3.00

`Net::SMTP` version 2.31_1 (newest pre 3.00 in libnet) overwrites mechanism in `Authen::SASL` with mechanism listed in `EHLO` reply.  Below please find my **UGLY** fix.

```
use Net::SMTP::SSL;
use Authen::SASL;

my ( $host, $port, $user, $pass ) = ( '...', '...', '...', '...' );    # fill correct data

my $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new( $host, Port => $port, Debug => 1 );
my $auth = Authen::SASL->new(
  mechanism => 'PLAIN LOGIN',
  callback  => { user => $user, pass => $passwd }
);
{
  no warnings 'redefine';
  my $count;
  local *Authen::SASL::mechanism = sub {
    my $self = shift;

    # Fix Begin
    # ignore first setting of mechanism
    if ( !$count++ && @_ && $Net::SMTP::VERSION =~ /^2\./ ) {
      return;
    }

    # Fix End
    @_
      ? $self->{mechanism} = shift
      : $self->{mechanism};
  };
  $smtp->auth($auth);
}
```

---

Code requiring fixing - [Net::SMTP 2.31_1 from libnet 1.22_01](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GBARR/libnet-1.22_01/Net/SMTP.pm)

```
sub auth {
  my ($self, $username, $password) = @_;

  ...

  my $mechanisms = $self->supports('AUTH', 500, ["Command unknown: 'AUTH'"]);
  return unless defined $mechanisms;

  my $sasl;

  if (ref($username) and UNIVERSAL::isa($username, 'Authen::SASL')) {
    $sasl = $username;
    $sasl->mechanism($mechanisms); # <= HERE Authen::SASL mechanism overwrite 
  }
```

Comment: you should `use Net::SMTP::SSL`; with this change it works on Debian 8 and 9, thanks!

Comment: @WojciechDyżewski fixed

Answer (score 2):

### Net::SMTP version above 3.00

`Net::SMTP` above version 3:
* does not overwrite mechanism in `Authen::SASL` parameter of `auth` method
* supports `STARTTLS` and smtps

```
use Net::SMTP;
use Authen::SASL;

my($host, $user, $pass) = ('...','...','...'); # fill correct data

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new( $host, SSL=>1, Debug => 1 ); # SSL=>1 - use smtps
$smtp->auth(
  Authen::SASL->new(
    mechanism => 'PLAIN LOGIN',
    callback  => { user => $user, pass => $passwd }
  )
);
```

Comment: [Perl 5.20 `Net::SMTP->new`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.20.2/Net/SMTP.html#CONSTRUCTOR) can't start SSL connection (`SSL => 1`)
EDIT: and can't `$smtp->auth($sasl_object)` :(
but your solution works on Debian 9 (Perl 5.24)

Comment: Could you post 1) EXACT error messages 2) versions of Net::SMTP, Net::SMTP::SSL and Authen::SASL you would like to use